# AMD GPU driver installation on Kubuntu 16.04?

Tags: drivers

How to install AMD GPU drivers on 16.04? My GPU is a Radeon HD 7640G+HD 7670M dual graphics.

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04,  open-source driver AMDGPU is enabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install additional AMD drivers in 16.04.  There is just no support or proprietary drivers for it, and as of this writing, there is still no plan to make any, or to further support AMD card beyond the existing opensource drivers.

Even if you do manage to mangle an install and make it run, it will likely break the system.

The issue with the open source drivers in 16.04 is power management, or lack thereof, for many cards.  Having a hybrid card means you will be running both at all times with no ability to power down the one not in use. This is not very effective for power consumption, and in the case of laptops, causes extra unneeded heat.